# Is it possible to rewrite selectors using reselect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, reselect

I am using the redux toolkit in my project.
My selector looks like this:

```
export const selectFilterCinemas = (state) =>
    state.filmSlice.cinemas.filter(
        (cinema) =>
            cinema.name.toLowerCase().includes(state.filmSlice.search.toLowerCase()) ||
            cinema.address.toLowerCase().includes(state.filmSlice.search.toLowerCase())
    )
```

Is it possible to rewrite my selector using reselect and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to use the `createSelector` API from Reselect, extract the pieces of data that you need through "input selectors", and then derive the actual results in the output function:

```js
const selectFilterCinemas = createSelector(
  (state) => state.filmSlice.cinemas,
  (state) => state.filmSlice.search,
  (cinemas, search) => {
    const lowerSearch = search.toLowerCase();
    return cinemas.filter(cinema => {
      return cinema.name.toLowerCase().includes(lowerSearch) ||
              cinema.address.toLowerCase().includes(lowerSearch);
    })
  }
)
```

That way the filtering will only re-run if either `cinemas` or `search` changes.

Also see the Redux docs page on [Deriving Data With Selectors](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors).

Comment: you have a fingerprint

cinema.address.toLowerCase().includes(lowerSearch);

Comment: Fixed, thank you!